# How to enter in NGXS selector when unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

Subscribing to the selector teamMemberService$ should return a list, and then there is some checking going on. I need to test this piece of code, but I don't know how to get into this type of subscription.

```
    if (this.doctor != undefined) {
      this.store.dispatch(new SearchTeamMemberData(this.doctor));
      this.teamMemberService$.subscribe((res) => {
        res.forEach((element) => {
          if (element.id !== 0) {
            this.teamList = res;
          } else {
            this.listZoroh = res;
          }
        });
        this.isLoading$.subscribe((res) => {
          this.isLoading = res;
        });
      });
    }
```

Test:

```
it("should subscribe to selector", () => {
    const doctor = {
      id: 9090900,
      name: "DOKTOR",
      surname: "TESTNI DRUGI",
      mbr: "111111111",
      mbo: "214000010",
      isReplacement: true,
      role: "doctor",
      hasFileExchPermission: false,
      displayName: "DOC",
    };
    component.doctor = doctor;
    const spy = jest.spyOn(component.teamMemberDetails$, "subscribe");
    component.getView();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Since the subscription should return a list, I tried adding this to my test (as seen here https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/482)

```
Object.defineProperty(component, "teamMemberDetails$", { writable: true });
component.teamMemberDetails$ = of([{ id: 1 }]);
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

And now I am clueless. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance missing the dispatch event in your test - maybe it needs to be added to a beforeEach method in the test suite to set things up? See https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown

```
  this.store.dispatch(new SearchTeamMemberData(this.doctor));
```

Comment: Interesting point, but it didn't help in this case. The thing is, this test covers dispatching that action, it just stops executing when reaches the selector.

Comment: In that case - you want to inspect what res is in the subscriber args. If it’s an object you can’t forEach on it, if it’s undefined you’ve got a sync error. Add `debugger` before `res.forEach` and inspect inside the subscribe method (or console.log it)

Comment: I did console log it, and yes, it does give me undefined. I will continue debugging. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can't seem to move on. I am stuck. Could you give me more information about "sync error" ? Does this mean a connection between component and test?

Comment: I just realized I was using the wrong selector the whole time! They had a very similar name, and jest was throwing errors for both of them. My mistake! :D